# Getting an edit text value into a double - always gets zero (android studio, java)

Tags: java, android, double, converters

I am making an android app - I had many errors when I managed to get i running a problem emerged. I have to get  the value of an edit text and turn it into a double, at first it was not working at all (the app crashed because of it) then I managed to get it running but now it is always a zero

For an example every  time method c2f is called the resukt is 32 ...

```
**Main activity:**

input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convert);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    c2f = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.c2f);
    c2k = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.c2k);
    f2c = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.f2c);
    f2k = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.f2k);
    k2c = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.k2c);
    k2f = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.k2f);

    double w;

    try {
        w = new Double(input.getText().toString());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        w = 0;
    }


    final double finalW = w;
    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (c2f.isChecked())
            {
                result.setText(Converter.c2f(finalW)+ "F");
            } else if (c2k.isChecked())
            {
                result.setText(Converter.c2k(finalW)+ "K");
            } else if (f2c.isChecked())
            {
                result.setText(Converter.f2c(finalW)+ "C");
            } else if (f2k.isChecked())
            {
                result.setText(Converter.f2k(finalW)+ "K");
            } else if (k2c.isChecked())
            {
                result.setText(Converter.k2c(finalW)+ "C");
            } else if (k2f.isChecked())
            {
                result.setText(Converter.k2f(finalW)+ "F");
            }

        }
    });


}}
```

**Class Convert**

```
public class Converter
```

{
    public  static double c2f (double w ) {return w*9/5+32;}
    public  static double c2k (double w )
    {
        return w+273.15;
    }
    public  static double f2c (double w )
    {
        return (w-32)*5/9;
    }
    public  static double f2k (double w ) {return (w+ 459.67)*5/9;}
    public  static double k2c (double w )
    {
        return w-273.15;
    }
    public  static double k2f (double w )
    {
        return w*1.8 - 459.67;
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

This is because exception is thrown and you have set `w = 0;` inside the catch block. Use this:

```
try {
    w = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString().trim());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    w = 0;
}
```

Also you may think of setting the inputType of your editText to number from xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I have it specified in my xml. Did get where I shoud put the:  w = Double.parseDouble(input.getText().toString().trim());

Answer (score 0):

```
/**Simply you can use below code snipet**/

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/input"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number or numberDecimal"
    android:lines="1"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:maxLines="1" />

 try
 {
    double value = Double.valueOf(input.getText().toString());
 }
 catch (NumberFormatException ex)
 {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```